# shorten url with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an old system and would like to shorten the URL.

At the moment:
`www.site.com/app/views/accessories.php`

I would like to open it like this:
`www.site.com/accessories.php`

I tried to do like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/Views/$1 [NC,QSA]
```

But this error appears "**Internal Server Error**". What is wrong?

My folder structure is as follows:

[image]

As you can see the files are not in the root. They are inside two `app/views/` folders.

Because of that the pages are opening with big and ugly links.

```
www.site.com/app/views/acessorios.php
www.site.com/app/views/clientes.php
www.site.com/app/views/empresas.php
```

I wish I could open them like this:

```
www.site.com/acessorios.php OR www.site.com/acessorios
www.site.com/clientes.php   OR www.site.com/clientes
www.site.com/empresas.php   OR www.site.com/empresas
```

That is, without looking like `app/views/` in the url.

Comment: Not sure the exact problem. I'm seeing `Views` versus `views` so that could be something. However, the `-f` and `-d` is "if no file or directory exists" which is basically just hijacking Apache's 404 system, which means _all_ 404's, including yours and attackers, will go to this place. You might want to make this a little more exclusive. Also, keeping the file extension, although not wrong, mentally muddies things, and I'd recommend dropping it to just `/accessories`

Comment: @ChrisHaas Can you send me a code suggestion for me to test here?

Comment: @Tiago, So you mean you are hitting `www.site.com/app/views/accessories.php` url and it should redirect(change url in browser) to `www.site.com/accessories.php`? Please confirm once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 exactly, that with all the pages that are in the app/views/ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples and attempts please try following .htaccess rules file. Make sure to place your .htaccess rules file along with your app folder(not inside it, along side it). Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /app/views/

##External redirect rules from here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/app/views/([^.]*\.php)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules from here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]*\.php)/?$ /app/views/$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Rules to redirect URLs to `www.site.com/acessorios` are as follows:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /app/views/

##External redirect rules from here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/app/views/([^.]*)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules from here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /app/views/$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: hello, I did as you said, but this message is appearing https://i.imgur.com/3jEWARM.png. What would be wrong?

Comment: If I say `www.site.com/clients` it will open the page `www.site.com/app/views/clients.php`... Too many pages

Comment: @Tiago, but you mentioned you are hitting link like www.site.com/app/views/accessories.php in your question's comments. Kindly confirm once.

Comment: Sorry for any mistakes, I'm using google translator.

Comment: @Tiago, No problem I understand. Can you please do let me know what link/URL you are hitting in your browser? And then let me know what URL it should become after redirection?

Comment: At the moment: www.site.com/app/views/accessories.php >>>> I would like to open it like this: www.site.com/accessories.php >>>> www.site.com/accessories

Comment: Open this way any page that is inside the `/app/views/` folder

Comment: I updated the post with more information `Edit 1`

Comment: @Tiago, again could you please confirm what link you are hitting in browser?

Comment: This division says. Currently and expected. https://i.imgur.com/DI9B3XW.png

Comment: @Tiago, Place your .htaccess along side with `app` folder(NOT inside it, along side with it) and try my **updated** rules once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248845/discussion-between-tiago-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @Tiago, Sorry I can't join chat please comment here itself. Thank you.

Comment: OK. Here i.imgur.com/XFaOWa0.png? Shouldn't it be in the root folder?

Comment: @Tiago, wherever your `app` folder is present put it there along with it(NOT inside it) simple and try then.

Comment: @Tiago, No, place .htaccess in `/carros.com` folder please.

Comment: but it is the main folder. It's a subdomain. The .htaccess file is at the root of the project.

Comment: All this is the root of this project https://i.imgur.com/9F3TNOc.png

Comment: @Tiago, Ok please try my code once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Not Found -> https://i.imgur.com/c670UPe.png

Comment: @Tiago, Are you hitting link `www.site.com/app/views/accessories.php`?

Comment: Yup. when I use `www.site.com/app/views/acessprios.php` it automatically changes to `www.site.com/acessorios.php` and shows `Internal Server Error`. When I access `www.site.com/acessorios` without .PHP, `Not Found` appears.

Comment: @Tiago, Ok try my **edited** rules and try hitting link `www.site.com/app/views/acessprios.php` once? Let me know how it goes.

Comment: It looks like it's working fine. Last doubt. If I want to open `www.site.com/acessorios` without .php, what do I need to change? And when you need to pass a parameter like `www.site.com/acessoriosEdit/1` how would it look

Comment: Because sometimes, I need to pass some parameters. At least 1, but it has comments that can reach 3~4 parameters.

Comment: @Tiago, I added 1 more solution for redirecting URL to `www.site.com/acessorios` also. For parameter passing question, please open a new question that will be better In my humble opinion, cheers.

Comment: I'll mark it now as resolved. Would it be possible to put an example passing parameters?

Comment: @Tiago, To be honest, I would like to request you to open a new question since I am already covering 2 cases here :) We can definitely discuss it there since these are resolved now, cheers.

Comment: I will send new link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74088185/modify-code-htaccess-to-accept-parameters-via-url

Comment: Do you understand this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74089397/simple-template-import

Comment: @Tiago, I am sorry, I don't know php.

Comment: How do I make it accept this path too, example: `www.site.com/json/acessorios.php`. Inside this json folder I will put some specific code.

Comment: I'm having problems ``Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error``, how to fix this?