# Modify code htaccess to accept parameters via URl

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Modify code to accept parameters via URl. Rules to redirect URLs to `www.site.com/acessorios.php` tried are as follows, where .htaccess rules file is present along side with `app` folder.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /app/views/

##External redirect rules from here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/app/views/([^.]*\.php)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules from here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]*\.php)/?$ /app/views/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Samples:

```
www.site.com/accessories.php?id=1
www.site.com/accessories.php?id=1&name=Tiago
www.site.com/accessories.php?id=1&name=Tiago&image=foto.png
```

Samples:

```
www.site.com/accessories/1
www.site.com/accessories/1/Tiago
www.site.com/accessories/1/Tiago/foto.png
```

This order may be different

Comment: Thanks for sharing your htaccess rules. Request you to please **keep only 1 set of rules** in Question **and** post samples of URLs also like **from** which url **to** which url you want to redirect? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question @Tiago, so you are hitting `www.site.com/accessories.php?id=1` in browser? Is it right?

Comment: Yes correct....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /app/views/

##External redirect rules from here....
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]*)\.php\?id=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]*)\.php\?id=(\d+)&name=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRUle ^  /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]*)\.php\?id=(\d+)&name=(\S+)&image=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  /%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=301,L]


##Internal rules from here onwards....
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /app/views/$1.php?id=$2&name=$3&image=$4 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /app/views/$1.php?id=$2&name=$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /app/views/$1.php?id=$2 [QSA,L]
```