# Simple template import

Tags: php

How to make it so that when you access a simple page like CONTACT.PHP, it already comes with the main html embedded (TEMPLATE.PHP): Example:

**PAGE CONTENT "CONTACT.PHP"**

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off" class="logg">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="aaa" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" value="" required/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="aaa" class="control-label">Email</label>
                <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" value="" required/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right"> Save </button>
</form>
```

**PAGE CONTENT "TEMPLATE.PHP"**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>


    <!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS -->

        <?= contact page here ?>    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                                    
    <!-- PAGE CONTENT ENDS -->


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Operation:
When the contato.php page is accessed, the template would also be loaded so that the layout is fully assembled.

Comment: you should add a form action if you want to post to a specific handler/file, other than that there should be no issues using [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) /  [require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) to bring in the other file

Comment: @LawrenceCherone but the template (TEMPLATE.PHP) will always be the same. What changes is the page, in this example I only provided a contact form, but it can be any other type.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It can be a customer list, where the base (TEMPLATE.PHP) is the same, it will only change what will appear inside the CONTENT.